# Issue with common Regex for alphabets and numbers

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex - `[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,18}` which means I can use alphabets and numbers with minimum length as 9 and maximum length as 18.  It should not take special characters.
It takes values like `ADV0098890` etc. but it is also taking `ADV0098890[]`, which is wrong.

How can I prevent that?

Comment: It does not include `[]` for me: Look at [this](https://www.regex101.com/r/vO2iE8/1)

Comment: Use anchors `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,18}$`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is matching only the first part of the string. Try wrapping the pattern in `^$`:

```
>> !!('ADV0098890'   =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,18}/)
=> true
>> !!('ADV0098890[]' =~ /[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,18}/)
=> true
>> !!('ADV0098890'   =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,18}$/)
=> true
>> !!('ADV0098890[]' =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{9,18}$/)
=> false
```